# How do I solve "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled"?

Tags: react-native, expo

I wanted to make my website to an application. I ran `npx create-react-app` and I made a react app. Then, I did what was in expo. I ran `expo install react-native-webview` and I changed my app.js to

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://expo.io' }} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />;
  }
}
```

with my url. However when I did `npm start` there was an error like this:

```
node_modules\react-native-webview\lib\WebView.js:
    Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
```